Excel script wastes a lot of time in a Power Automate flow because of "Text in columns" conversion
I’ve been working on an Excel script for a while to execute it from a Power Automate flow, which would send tables via email after being generated with a Power BI query.
The issue is that when the Excel table is created, I have 10 numeric columns that Excel interprets as text, and I need to change this to apply conditional formatting formulas. The tables have between 50 and 400 rows. To force the number format, I use the "Text to Columns" function, which takes 23 minutes(!!). The big issue with the Power Automate flow is that it seems to hang, as there are 9 emails, each with a table in a separate sheet. ¿Is there any way to improve performance, so that the text-to-number conversion isn’t so slow? May be another function that hasn't to read and write in a loop each cell from the column?
I tried measuring the performance locally in Excel and in Excel on the web, and this particular step within the loops always takes a long time. The table is generated from a JSON that I convert to HTML, and then to Excel. (Maybe I could set the column as numeric in a previous step?)
I attached the script, generated by excel itself and "tuned" by me. Sorry, it´s too long, the main part I'm interested is the loops and the code inside, if you guess any solution!
Thanks in advance!
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
//here comes some formatting code.

    // Text to columns on range N1:N200 on selectedSheet
    for (let row = 0; row < table1.getColumn("Avg delay asist").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount() ; row++) {
        let sourceRange = selectedSheet.getRange("N1:N600");
        let destinationRange = selectedSheet.getRange("N1");
        let sourceRangeValues = sourceRange.getRow(row).getValues()[0][0].toString().split(/[\t]/)
        destinationRange.getOffsetRange(row, 0).getResizedRange(0, sourceRangeValues.length - 1).setValues([sourceRangeValues]);
    }
//this loop is repeated for other 10 columns in this table. After these 10 loops, the code for conditional formatting comes, which requires numbers for its formulas.

}


Perhaps this is quicker: Write the TEXTSPLIT function into column O and after that replace its results with values and then delete column N

Thanks @jkpieterse, I solved this problem creating a 'temp' column and copying&pasting the text:
table1.addColumn(-1, null, "temp");
let col = table1.getColumnByName("temp");
let act = table1.getColumnByName("Total");
col.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().setFormula("=VALUE([@[Total]])")
act.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(0).copyFrom( table1.getColumn("temp").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal(), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);

I hope this can help another else...
